# Form background color change

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the color of the form text box based on the input the user submitted. But the change in color is only visible after changing the input, why?

```js
function clickedFree() {
  var input = document.getElementById("answer");
  if (input.value == "1971") {
    document.getElementById("answerFree").innerHTML = "Correct!";
    input.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("answerFree").innerHTML = "Incorrect";
    input.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<p id="answerFree"></p>
<form onsubmit="return clickedFree()">
  <input name="answer" id="answer" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Check answer" />
</form>
```

Comment: May you also include the HTML for `answerFree`?

Comment: The color changes after the input is submitted, which seems reasonable. But "the change in color is only visible after changing the input, why?" sounds like you want to know why the color does not change before you change the input?

Comment: The updated code seems to work just fine. What do you expect to happen different to what it does?

Comment: For example, if I type in 7 and click check (the incorrect word appears) but the color is still blue. And if I remove 7 or add anything(type 8 after it) the color red suddenly appears. I want the red  color to appear as soon as I click check not after making modification to the answer.

Comment: @newbie blue? What browser are you using?

Comment: Microsoft edge.

Answer (score 1):

```
function clickedFree()
        {
            var input = document.getElementById("answer");
            if (input.value == "1971")
            {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Correct!";
                input.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Incorrect";
                input.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Code only answers are not really helpful. Please explain why/how it should solve the question.

Comment: I guess just typos: `answerFree` -> `answer`